# How do I connect to SQL Server using Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server Express on a remote PC using a C# application. When I run the application on my local PC to a local server, it works without any issues. When I use Remote Desktop to connect to a client PC, and run the app (I changed the connection string to the local server address), I get an error:

> Error 26: error locating server/instance specified**

Could the issue be in my connection string?

I have tried multiple changes to my connection string (see code below) and even tried the whole UDP connection 1433 TCP/IP port change.

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=1FEPINMA02\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Indigo; User Id=IndigoUser; Password=IndigoUser ;User Instance=False;");

//SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DAVIDBRITS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Indigo;Integrated Security=True "); // <---------- This is commented out because we tried this also.
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: I would try to connect with sql management studio at first.

Comment: @ibram Thank you for your response. I can connect via SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you. I will try this and update if it works.

Comment: firewall has been setup to allow SQL Server port ?

Comment: Is SQL Server Browser running on the remote pc?

Comment: Account should have access on Machine and SQL instance both. If machines lie in different networks you may need to check with the Admin guy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sqlconstringx = "Data Source=ipaddress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User ID=MyUsername;password=MyPassword;";
```

please try.

make sure you can ping the server

Comment: It is conection to an instance , not the default port, so your answer should read `ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS`